# Python Pandas Dataframe duplicate and reorder a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a (probably) pretty easy problem. I have the following DataFrame:

c1 | c2 | c3

a    |    b    |   4
   b    |    a    |   1

Now column3 depends only on column1 and column2 has the same items as column1, but in different order. All I am trying to do is add a column4 with the same values of column3 but in order of column2. So the result would look like this:

```
c1| c2| c3|c4

a | b | 4 | 1             
b | a | 1 | 4
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `same values of column3 but in order of column2` what do you mean by order of column2 here. is it sorted by column 2 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If values are unique:

```
df['c4'] = df.set_index('c1').loc[df['c2'], 'c3'].values
print (df)
  c1 c2  c3  c4
0  a  b   4   1
1  b  a   1   4
```

If not, it is a bit complicted, because need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for create unique `MultiIndex` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
  c1 c2  c3
0  a  b   5
1  a  a   4
2  b  a   1

a = df.groupby('c1').cumcount()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.groupby('c2').cumcount(), df['c2']])
print (idx)
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
           names=[None, 'c2'])

df['c4'] = df.set_index([a,'c1']).reindex(idx)['c3'].values
print (df)
  c1 c2  c3  c4
0  a  b   5   1
1  a  a   4   5
2  b  a   1   4
```

Comment: How do you always answer these questions so quickly? You never sleep?

Comment: Here is 12:44, so I sleep at night :)

Comment: Cool man. I am a huge fan. Whenever a pandas question comes, by the time I copy the data frame your answer is in. :)

Comment: Haha wow that was way faster than expected :D Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: AH no wait sorry, the values are not unique :( so in c1 and c2 are the same values but multiple times and in a different order. The overall goal is actually to duplicate all other depending columns of c1 to c2's order.

Comment: @SirTobi - It is a bit complicated, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not as nice as @jezrael answer but works:

```
df['c4'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(df['c1'], df['c3'])).get(x['c2']), axis=1)

  c1 c2  c3  c4
0  a  b   4   1
1  b  a   1   4
```